# Animated text with CSS/JS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I saw a really cool animation on a website a while back and it's something I'd like to learn to do, as I have a chance to implement something like this on a project of my own. Could someone experienced in front-end work tell me what this is and maybe point me in the right direction?

On this side here: reflektive.com you'll see in the slider, under the text "Talent Development", how the text changes and sort of scrolls in.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: can you provide some reference..reflektive.com is not opening

Comment: Google "css animation" and you will find a bazillion tutorials to learn it.

Comment: Have you used browser dev tools to inspect the elements and see what css is applied?

Comment: @C14L, thanks - I know how to google CSS animation. I am trying to find information this specific animation and because I am not a CSS/JS expert, I wouldn't even know what this particular animation is, to look for it. Which is why I am attempting to ask the more experienced.... To clarify, I have searched animations, haven't come across THIS particular animation.

Comment: I am getting a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED for the above domain.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) library. Same library used on the site which you mentioned in your question.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> // jquery library
<script src="typed.js"></script> // typed.js library
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".element").typed({
            strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
            typeSpeed: 0
        });
    });
</script>


<span class="element"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a link... Is this is the animation you are expecting?

http://codepen.io/rusjames/pen/uAFhE

```
@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2{
  0%{width: 0;}
  50%{width: 0;}
  100%{ width: 100; } 
}


p{
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not. After digging some more, I can see that it isn't CSS at all for the animation, its JQuery. The standard JQuery library hasn't worked, so it must be a 3rd party library. Thank you though, I appreciate your input.